# Signing up for a new account using the Flickr APA

Tags: flickr

Does anybody know whether it is possible use the Flickr's API to register a new account? We would like to use our website to allow user to register with us and Flickr at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything applicable in the list of methods at http://www.flickr.com/services/api/.  All of the calls in the flickr.people.* category are finds and gets.

Comment: Thanks. I have since contacted Yahoo! Flickr and they confirmed that it is not possible.